# Angular 2 getElementById innered div

Tags: javascript, html, angular, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I would like to ask if it is possible to get innered div through javascript getElementById function.

```
this.treeContent = this.treeContent +
          '<div id="tree' + htmlData.Id +
          '" class="col-md-12">' + htmlData.Label + '</div>';

          document.getElementById('tree' + htmlData.Id).innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="button' + htmlData.Id +
          '"  value="' + htmlData.Id + '">'
           + htmlData.Label + '</button>';
```

When i try code like this Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error rises. Thank you in advance for all replies.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in your controller rather than in your template?

Answer (score 0):

You get Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error because you are trying to call document.getElementById and the element you want to get is not part of the DOM yet.

Comment: I use angular [innerHTML] in html template so after changes of treeContent variable elements add automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try binding to tree content like this:

```
<div innerHtml="{{treeContent}}"></div>
```

By the way, you should try keeping as much HTML out of your JS files as possible.  See https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data.

Comment: No changes. Yes you are right but i want to visualize tree structured data and for some reasons i cant use libraries for that. Number of elements changes dynamically so i cant create html templat manually.